# Error with CJSONDeserializer IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, json

I am new with XCode and iOS. I want to create a `BD` at a remote web service. 
My problem is with this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CJSONDeserializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have a target, with the group of project with viewController.h and .m And other group with JSON libraries. Maybe, i have to configure something. I don't know.

Comment: select the project parent folder on the left panel, and then select your target from there. go to "Build Phases" and check if the file is under the "Compile Sources" tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very similar:

1. Select the project in the project navigator.
2. Select the Target in the detail view.
3. Select the Build Phase tab.
4. Expand the Compiled Sources section
5. Add the file **CJSONDeserializer.m** if it is not present there.

This will hopefully solve your problem